# Prolog - Variable as operator

Tags: prolog

I have an operator stored in a variable Op and two integers are stored in X and Y. Now, I want to do something like (Z is X Op Y), but this syntax seems not to be correct.

Does anybody know if there is a way to do this in Prolog?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do it by building the predicate using the =.. operator.

try it like:

```
compute(X,Y,Op,Z) :-
   Eq=..[Op, X, Y],
   Z is Eq.
```

An operator is really just like any other functor.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the effect:

```
operator(Z,X,plus,Y):-Z is X + Y.  
operator(Z,X,times,Y):-Z is X * Y.
```

I tried this on ideone.com for SWI-Prolog with:

```
OP=times, operator(Z,3,OP,8).
```

And I got:

```
OP = times,
Z = 24.
```